# Disable auto-complete Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, keyboard

How do I prevent multiple inputs from occurring when holding down a key?

If I hold down a key like an arrow key it will repeat the key event rapidly. To prevent this I have tried

```
xset -r 103 r off
```

The reason for 103 is because `sudo showkey -k`
said the up arrow `^[[A`  was 103. Turning it off or on in the terminal seems to do nothing. I also tried `xev -event keyboard` and used that to get the keycode which said it was 111.

I am on Debian 12, gnome which i beleieve uses xwayland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article
[Repeating keystrokes when typing in a Linux virtual machine](https://kb.parallels.com/en/124863).
It has screenshots for Gnome 3 based desktops that show the following
bare procedure:

> 1. Open the **Activities** overview and start typing Settings.
> 2. Click **Settings**.
> 3. Click **Universal Access** in the sidebar.
> 4. Scroll down to the **Typing** section and click **Repeat Keys**.
> 5. Set **Repeat Keys** switch to **off**.
> 6. Alternatively, you can adjust the **Delay** slider, gradually increasing the value to the point where the issue disappears.